# Typescript + Ionic: Using filter on an Object

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3.x.

I wrote a basic chat app and want to be able to filter chats for words.

I have just tried to implement a searchbar into my application. I modified the HTML file like this:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-item *ngFor="let chat of tempChats">
```

In the HTML file I have an array of objects:

```
chats: Object[]=[];
tempChats: Object[]=[];
```

which I later fill with chats that have messages and titles. Like this:

```
this.chats.push({author: 'Jim',message: 'Hi!'});
```

Then I wrote an initializeChats function and a getItems function:

```
initializeChats(){
   this.tempChats=this.chats;
}

getItems(){
  this.initializeChats();
  let val = ev.target.value;
  if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.tempChats = this.tempChats.filter((chat) => {
      return (chat.message.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    })
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this gives the error:
Property ‘message’ does not exist on type ‘Object’.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:
Doing stuff like

```
for(chat of chats){
  alert(chat.name);
}
```

works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is just Typescript complaining about the type of the `chats` property, because the `Object` type definition does not define a `message` property.

Instead of this:

```
chats: Object[]=[];
tempChats: Object[]=[];
```

Declare both properties like this:

```
chats: Array<{ author: string, message: string }> = [];
tempChats: Array<{ author: string, message: string }> = [];
```

That way, you tell Typescript that the `chats` property is an array, and each object of that array has two properties, a `message` and an `author` (both of type string).

**EDIT**

A better way to handle this would be to create a new class with these properties, like this

```
export class ChatMessage {
  public author: string;
  public message: string;
}
```

And then you can use it to declare the `chats` property like this

```
chats: Array<ChatMessage> = [];
tempChats: Array<ChatMessage> = [];
```

---

**UPDATE**

Again, the error is not because that property does not exist in each object of the `chats` property, is just because Typescript thinks that each object from that array if of type `Object` and knows that the type `Object` does not have a property called `message`. This is an error related to Typescript (an thus, in compilation time).

If you don't know the shape of that class, you can let Typescript know that by declaring both arrays like this:

```
chats: Array<any> = [];
tempChats: Array<any> = [];
```

By using `any`, you're letting Typescript know that each object from that array could be anything, and will avoid the error you are facing.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but unfortunately this is not possible.
I get the chat messages from a server (without getting into too much complicated details), but their form has to be dynamic. They have in common though, that they always have an author and a message.

Another weird thing is, that if I were to write something like this
for(let chat of chats){ alert(chat.message)}
it works.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer. Please notice that Typescript only checks the type in compilation time, so the error does not mean that the object doesn't actually have a property with that name, *is just that Typescript does not know that*. By using `any` it should work just fine :)

Comment: Nice your answer works :) But does using any instead of object have any drawbacks? Like does that make the application significantly slower?

Comment: No, not at all. Typescript just checks the types and helps the developers to avoid common issues like assigning a number to a string property and so on (extremely common in javascript). But at the end the Typescript code is transpiled to plain javascript, so declaring a property as `any` or `Object` is exactly the same at the end in the javascript code.